# How to telnet to a computer which is sharing a single public ip?

Tags: ip

Suppose that I am sharing a public ip 56.162.XXX.XXX with some other users. Now I have a local ip that I see if I type ipconfig in the command prompt. That is 192.168.2.3. Now I have a program running on port 3630 listening to any incoming connection. I can call myself with the help of loop back ip ie. telnet 127.0.0.1 3630, and i see that two programs are getting connected and can exchange data. I can also telnet and get connected with my laptop from another laptop which is sharing same public ip as mine by the command telnet 192.168.4.20 3630. But how should I do the same from a remote computer? I mean a computer which has a different public ip.
Actually I want something like "telnet public ip(local ip) port no". The other computer is also sharing a public ip with some other users.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setup some kind of NAT (Network Address Translation) or PAT (Port Address Translation) that will forward the requests for port 3630 to your local IP.

The actual configuration to use will depend on your firewall/router. If you have a standard ADSL router, there is likely to be a configuration page in there that will allow you to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to read up on port forwarding and NAT.

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Port_forwarding

Comment: Do you think IPV6 is any better that way? I guess this had to be done as number of IPs in IPV4 weren't enough or else why would some machines have to be put under a common public IP if a distinct one is easily available. Well I am not considering the case where the users explicitly would like to look like a single one to the outer world.